# Laravel Nesting relationship returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have next db structure:

[image]

And I have next code in my Eloquent models:

**Sample.php**

```
public function polfzms()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Polfzm');
}
```

**Polfzm.php**

```
public function samples()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sample');
}

public function gene()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Gene');
}
```

**Gene.php**

```
public function polfzms()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Polfzm');
}
```

I try to get sample data with his labels, polfzms and gene using dot in where clause - `polfzms.gene`

```
public function show($id)
{
    return Sample::with('labels', 'polfzms.gene')->findOrFail($id);
}
```

But I have got a `"gene":null`

```
{
   "id":18,
   "person_id":1,
   "prefix_id":3,
   "labels":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Name1",
         "meaning":"dfdf",
         "pivot":{
            "sample_id":18,
            "label_id":1
         }
      },
   ],
   "polfzms":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"G20210",
         "id_gene":1,
         "pivot":{
            "sample_id":18,
            "polfzm_id":1
         },
         "gene":null
      }
   ]
}
```

I use latest laravel version. How can I fix it?

Comment: Track the query, use debugbar for that; run the query within your SQL client. Good luck. What is `polfzm`?

Comment: You might need to provide the custom id field in the many to many relationship. eg. something like ```$this->belongsTo('App\Gene',  'id_gene');```. Depends how you have set it up.

Comment: @Kyslik Short name of 'polymorphism'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `null` for your `Gene` relation, because you have not explicitly defined a foreign key, nor followed the Eloquent naming convention.

Eloquent expects the foreign key to be `gene_id`, whereas your schema has the foreign key `id_gene`.

To fix this, either change your schema to define the foreign key as `gene_id`, or update your relationship as follows:

```
public function gene()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Gene', 'id_gene');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed it. I renamed the column and everything works now